# rails select with jquery multi select is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-multiselect

rails select field, with jquery multi select is not working in rails. When we select the multiple options and save, it is showing only single option as selected(not all the selected options are showing.)

I am having the following select field,

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>In which form the funds are held?  </label></br>
      <%= f.select :form_of_funds__c, options_for_select(['Savings account', 'Fixed deposit','Sale of property'], @entrepreneur.form_of_funds__c), {class: "form-control", prompt: "Please select"},{ :multiple => true, :size => 5 } %>          
    </div>
```

and the following jquery logic.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#cp_entrepreneur_form_of_funds__c, 
     #cp_entrepreneur_funds_held_on__c').multiselect({
     numberDisplayed: 4
   });
   });
```

below is the rails server log.

```
Started PATCH "/investor_create_or_update" for ::1 at 2019-01-02 12:30:27 +0530
DEBUG: Chewy strategies stack: [2] <- atomic @ /home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/chewy-0.8.2/lib/chewy/railtie.rb:16
Processing by InvestorVisaController#investor_create_or_update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "cp_entrepreneur"=>{"access_to_at_least_aud_40_000__c"=>"", "total_net_worth__c"=>"", "source_of_the_funds__c"=>"form-control", "funds_be_legaly_transferred_to_australia__c"=>"", "form_of_funds__c"=>["", "Savings account", "Sale of property"]*, "funds_held_on__c"=>["", "Main applicant (you)", "your spouse"],* "value_of_total_assests__c"=>"", "what_is_the_reason_for_applying_for_the__c"=>"", "status_of_property__c"=>"", "do_you_have_stable_and_regular_resources__c"=>"", "provide_evidence_for_lawful_source__c"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save and Continue"}
SET Action : investor_visa_investor_create_or_update
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1836]]
  CP::Entrepreneur Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "booking_informations__c".* FROM "booking_informations__c" WHERE "booking_informations__c"."primary_email_id__c" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["primary_email_id__c", "test_server4564645@gmail.com"]]
Unpermitted parameters: form_of_funds__c, funds_held_on__c
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "booking_informations__c" SET "access_to_at_least_aud_40_000__c" = $1, "source_of_the_funds__c" = $2, "funds_be_legaly_transferred_to_australia__c" = $3, "status_of_property__c" = $4, "provide_evidence_for_lawful_source__c" = $5 WHERE "booking_informations__c"."heroku_id" = $6  [["access_to_at_least_aud_40_000__c", ""], ["source_of_the_funds__c", "form-control"], ["funds_be_legaly_transferred_to_australia__c", ""], ["status_of_property__c", ""], ["provide_evidence_for_lawful_source__c", ""], ["heroku_id", 2]]
   (14.6ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Did you check your web console, which error are you getting ?

Comment: i am not geting any eror. Please check the modified question.

Comment: seems like there is something wrong in your controller. Because in the logs, I can see array `["", "Savings account", "Sale of property"]`

Comment: @John i am talking about web console of browser, not rails logs